# Does PayPal Donate support Payment Data Transfer?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-pdt

I'm setting up a PayPal Donate button with a personal account. I cannot find a way to setup Payment Data Transfer for Return URL with the PayPal Donate button. It worked a year ago (2018), but it seems to have been discontinued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there was some talk of the discontinuation of PayPal's PDT. Whether or not that has happened, I believe that the general consensus is that you should likely switch your button notifications to the *Instant Payment Notification* (IPN) system. There are several reasons for this:

PDT has some major disadvantages, as discussed in [this PayPal doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/#when-to-use-pdt)

The same link discusses how IPN resolves these disadvantages.

The fact that the IPN sends notification for all of your payer/payee interactions allows you and your business to provide *the very basic due diligence.* While there is some level of "opinion" involved, many people would consider this non-negotiable.